# Excess elements in scalar initializer after make an mutable variable

Tags: c

I get the error "Excess elements in scalar initializer" when I try to make init data so I can change the data when it need to me changed because before my data just define. But when I make an init then the error shows up. I don't really understand the error. Can anyone explain and give me an example of how to make it work?

```
int box[15][2] = {{0}};
    if (hand == "right"){
        box[15][2] = {{45,85}, {45, 75}, {45, 65}, {65, 85}, {65, 75}, {65, 65}, {25, 85}, {25, 75},
                           {25, 65}, {5, 85}, {5, 75}, {5, 65}, {85, 85}, {85, 75}, {85, 65}};
    }
```

Comment: `box[15][2]` is an element in the array, not the entire array.  Also, arrays are not assignable.

Comment: Pick a language.  C and C++ are very different.  Also, what do you think the comparison `hand == "right"` does in C?  Hint:  It's always going to be false.

Comment: Basically: you need to study arrays before you can use arrays. You can't learn C by trial & error, you need a good reference book.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. You can only use an initializer list to set an array when the array is declared. You cannot assign such a list to an already declared array.
2. `box[15][2]` is not a valid reference to `box`. (The last element is `box[14][1]`.)
3. `hand == "right"` makes no sense. You are comparing what is (hopefully) a `char` pointer to a pointer to the constant string "right". Even if `hand` had been set to that constant string, there is no guarantee that the same pointer would be used in the comparison. It looks like you want to compare the string at `hand` to `"right"`, which that doesn't do.

To set the array `box`, one way would be to make another constant array with what you want, and then using `memcpy()` to copy that over `box`.

To compare two strings, use `strcmp()`.